# See who starred a question

Tags: support, search, bookmarks

I could go to the user profile and see all of his stars (favourites) but how do you see who starred a question of yours or another one?

Comment: Be aware that some people merely use the stars as a way to "bookmark" a question that they might want to get back to in a few days.  It does not necessarily mean the star-er thinks the question is exceptional or anything.  It's not like a playlist.

Comment: @HotLicks I never thought that any of my questions was starred because it was exceptional. This is rather mere curiosity.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do that with the [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com).

You'd have to query the `Votes` table; rows with `Votes.VoteTypeId = 5` are favorite votes, and the `Vote.UserId` field is then populated.

[This query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/205985/who-favorited-me) finds all users that have starred questions you asked, for example.

Comment: + 1 Cool thanks! Hope this also useful for other curious people :D

Comment: Also cool because I (1) didn't know the Data Explorer thing existed, and (2) didn't know how they model the backend. VoteTypeId, eh? Huh. Assumedly in the actual code they use an enum, or all the magic numbers would get infuriating pretty quickly.

Comment: @ParthianShot: see the [schema documentation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede).

Comment: @MartijnPieters Wouldn't expose something like Data Explorer be prone to attacks by smartly crafted queries that exhaust the server? I know there is a captcha you have to solve before running the query but that type of captchas are easily solvable in an automated way. If it was already discussed can you link me to the question?

Comment: @BarackObama: The data explorer database is a *copy*; it is refreshed once a week. You are not querying the live Stack Overflow database.

Comment: @MartijnPieters But it's a copy that can be queried, where/how are those queries processed?. Guess that like with all queriable systems, with a computational expensive crafted query it can halt the system to a certain degree or totally.

Comment: @BarackObama: So? If you enter a query that takes too much time, it times out.

Comment: @BarackObama: look, the Stack Exchange team is *very competent* and can handle DOS, DDOS and other jokers just fine. There is little point in speculating about possible attacks here, as you have been told about before. If you have a **concrete** vulnerability, report it to the team directly.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Got it. So they use limits to avoid it. I also found they say it in this question http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87561/how-does-stackexchange-dataexplorer-prevent-dos-attacks where someone also says that *SEDE is isolated from SO/SE and therefore there isn't much to gain from a DOS attack*

Comment: Pretty sure it's also heavily cached. Confusing to me that even after the first call it still takes 7 seconds, however, you'll notice that the sql % is 0.0 on all attempts after the first with the same userid. It will also show in the bottom right whether or not it came from cache.